# Preventing main div from scrolling underneath Header

Tags: html, css

I have this problem where my "main" div which holds the content of the webpage scrolls under header and my nav bar. I've been looking around for solutions and people say to `position: fixed position: absolute`. However, when I try these the div still scrolls under the header and nav bar. I've also tried to set a `top: 980px;` To account for the pixel size of these two elements and it will still scroll.

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico);
 body {
  background-image: url("paws1.jpg");
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}
/* 
HEADER ELEMENTS 
*/

img {
  display: block;
}
header {
  width: 950px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 250px;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(144, 214, 32, 1);
  min-width: 950px;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0px;
}
header div {
  display: inline-block;
}
#nav {
  width: 950px;
  content: "";
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 0;
  position: fixed;
  min-width: 950px;
  background: #8BC43F;
  text-align: center;
}
#account {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  padding-top: 22px;
}
header ul {
  padding-left: 20px;
}
header li {
  display: inline-block;
}
header li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px;
}
header li a:hover {
  background: #571173;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
#current {
  background-color: rgba(255, 102, 0, 1);
  border-radius: 3px;
  z-index: 2;
}
/*
MAIN CONTENT
*/

#main {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  width: 950px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  min-width: 950px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  top: 980px;
}
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
#splash-left {
  float: left;
  width: 590px;
}
#splash-right {
  float: right;
  width: 300px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
#home-image {
  background: url(../images/mainimage.jpg);
  border-radius: 0px;
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 280px;
  text-align: center;
}
.splash-title {
  font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
  font-size: 5em;
}
footer {
  position: relative;
  height: 70px;
  padding-left: 230px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <header>
    <img src="Banner.jpg" width="946" height="246" alt="dogwash" style='border:2px solid #000000'>
    <div id="nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="Home">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="BathHouse">DIY Dog Bath House</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="Services">Professional Services</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="Products">Products</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="Contact">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div id="home-image">
    <div id="splash-left">
      <h1>Brockport, NY Dog Groomer</h1>
      <p><span style="font-size: large;">The Dog Wash "Do-It-Yourself" Bath House</span>
      </p>
      <p><strong>Keep your best friend clean and your house cleaner with our DIY dog bathing services! </strong>No appointments are necessary - just bring in your dog and we'll supply the rest. Bring your pooch into The Dog Wash "Do-It-Yourself" Bath House
        today!</p>
      <p>You'll have your own gated room equipped with a waist high tub, professional shampoos and conditioners, clean towels, an apron and more!</p>
      <p><strong>Professional, certified dog grooming services</strong>
        <br>We love your dog almost as much as you do! Certified groomer Patti Francisco has 7 years of experience, and will provide your dog with a gentle, professional trimming to help him look his best.</p>
      <p><strong>Get to know The Dog Wash!</strong>
      </p>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="http://diydogwash.com/brockport-ny-diy-dog-bathing.htm">DIY Dog Bath House </a>- No appointments necessary - leave the mess with us!</li>
        <li><a href="http://diydogwash.com/brockport-ny-dog-grooming.htm">Professional Services</a> - We also offer professional dog grooming by a certified groomer</li>
        <li><a href="http://diydogwash.com/brockport-ny-dog-grooming-supplies-collars-dog-toys.htm">Products</a> - Professional shampoos and conditioners, brand name collars and leads, and more</li>
      </ul>
      <p><strong>Cleanliness is king!</strong>
        <br>Sanitation is very important to us. That's why all of the tubs and equipment are fully cleaned and sanitized after each use.</p>
      <p><strong>Keep your dog clean without the mess! Call The Dog Wash at 585-637-7098 for a grooming appointment, or bring him into 4612 Lake Rd S. for DIY bathing services.</strong>
        <img src="Dogs.jpg" width="550" height="200" alt="dogs" align="right">
    </div>
    <div id="splash-right">
      <img src="Coupon.jpg" width="270" height="500" alt="coupon" style='border:2px solid #000000'>
    </div>
    <br clear="all" />
  </div>
</div>
<footer>
  <div id="footer">
    <br />
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/The-Dog-Wash-Do-It-Yourself-Bath-House-for-Pets/122644714485385" target="_blank">
      <img src="fb.png" width="50" height="50" alt="thumb">
    </a>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Here is the website link for a quick visual:
http://www.itss.brockport.edu/~rsiss1/cis442/ADogWash/Home

Comment: So you want the header and nav to scroll with the rest of the page?

Comment: Why are you using fixed positioning on the header?

Comment: Yes, I do want to the header and nav to scroll with the rest of the page. I'm assuming I can just remove the `top` element in the css but then it messes with the centered positioning. and I'm using fixed, to have the header centered on the page. I'm still pretty new to html

Comment: You have to remove the position fixed on your header and nav. They are fixing them to the top of the page. if something is fixed it stays in the position even if you scroll

Comment: You can press F12 in chrome and play around with the CSS to see how it looks when you remove the fixed position. Once you remove that you need to remove the large margins that you have given everything

Comment: That works for the Header, but when I apply that same fix to the nav bar. It creates some weird offset between the list in the div, and the background of the div. I'm updating the website link as these changes are made. If visuals are better than my explanations

Comment: You have your navigation in a <ul> you need to set the margin to 0px

Comment: There are also a few other things wrong with the website code but I can fix everything for you

Comment: If they're css code issues, then yeah I've kind of recycled an old template as it served almost the same purpose and I've been worrying more about the positioning than getting rid of code that doesn't do anything atm.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76544/discussion-between-andrew-and-ryan-sisson).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/t5fouf4u/1/. I can't see all your issues in the fiddle. So let me know if you have something else.

```
header {
  width: 950px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: rgba(144, 214, 32, 1);
  min-width: 950px;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0px;
}
header div {
  display: inline-block;
}
#nav {
  width: 950px;
  content: "";
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 0;
  min-width: 950px;
  background: #8BC43F;
  text-align: center;
}
#nav ul {
    margin:0px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! Also credit to @Andrew as he proposed this same solution in the comments above